# Checking dimensions of a factor variable in R

Tags: r, variables, inspection

This is a short question, but how do I look up the dimensions of a factor variable in R? I tried:

```
dim(X)
nrow(X)
ncol(X)
```

but all return `NULL`

Comment: You should reassign the word "dimensions"  in your R-brain convolutions or gyri to describe `matrices` and `data.frames`. In R these are NOT "dimensions".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If we have an atomic variable (which a factor is), it will  have a `length` value

```
X <- factor(letters)

length(X)

## [1] 26
```

It will also have `levels`

```
levels(x)
```

When `X` is a factor, it `is` the following classes

```
is(X)
[1] "factor"   "integer"  "oldClass" "numeric"  "vector"
```

Comment: And `levels(X)` might be useful.

Answer (score 1):

Also the str() function is helpful when one has a dataframe and needs to get an idea of many different levels at once.